# How to clear disk space in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

My disk in Google Colab is fulled mostly, while my ram there, is empty.
How can I clear my disk in Google Colab?

Comment: Are you connected to a runtime? 
Go to "Runtime"->"Change Runtime type" -> Choose Hardware accelerator -> "Save"